# Javascript how to resize and clip an image at the same time?

Tags: javascript, image, resize

I have an image with the original size: 374x144. It's 3images in one file. So i define a div tag to get just one image:

```
<div style="background-image:url('http://pics.kapihospital.de/ga_cars.5.jpg');position:absolute;height:48px;width:374;background-position: 0px -96px;"></div>
```

Now I want to resize the image/div tag. But when i change the height and with attribute I get a changed clip part and not a resized image.

It is possible to clip and risize an image at the same time? The new size should be someting around 179x23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an actual image tag to do the resizing and some kind of wrapper to do the clipping (I used a  `div`).

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <img src="http://pics.kapihospital.de/ga_cars.5.jpg" width="179" height="69">
</div>​​​​
```

**CSS**

```
DIV {
    width: 179px;
    height: 23px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

IMG {
    position: relative;
    top: -23px;
}
```

You can use `position: relative` on the image and shift it around in the `div` using a negative `top` property.